# @font-face no funciona en Android

Tags: html, css, fuentes

Tengo en mi sitio fuentes personalizadas, las subí a un servidor y funcionan en mi PC, en navegadores de escritorio correctamente, pero al revisarlo en mi dispositivo móvil Android, no funciona en ninguno de los navegadores. Estuve revisando ponerlo en diferentes formatos pero no funcionó. Alguna idea?

```
@font-face{
  font-family: mifuente;
  src:url(Fuentes/mifuente.otf);
  src:url(Fuentes/mifuente.eot);
  src:url(Fuentes/mifuente.ttf) format(truetype),
      url(Fuentes/mifuente.woff) format(woff),
      url(Fuentes/mifuente.woff2) format(woff2),
      url(Fuentes/mifuente.svg) format(svg);
}
```

Comment: Si agregas `format("opentype")` en el tipo `.otf` y con comillas `""` los otros formatos?

Comment: Cabo de probar lo de `format("opentype")` no funcionó, y si le pongo comillas a los otros formatos, me marca errores.